# Cache issue with NPM publish and Nexus groups

Tags: nexus, nexus3

We have the following setup in our Nexus (3.15.2-01) instance for NPM packages:

```
npm-group (npm: group)
├── npm-private-repository (npm: proxy)
└── npm-proxy-to-npmjs.com (npm: hosted)
```

When we publish a NPM package to npmjs.com, it is not immediately available in the proxy repository (meaning that **npm view my-package@x.y.z** returns no result. So far I understand there is cache on the proxy and I need to clear it on this proxy, nothing strange.

But what is curious is that clearing cache on the proxy repository is not enough, I also need to clear the cache on the group.

Is it an expected behaviour? I find it inconvenient because on a group there is no option to say "clear cache every n minutes" and therefore I need to do it manually. Also, I need to use the "admin" user to be able to click on the "Invalidate cache" button. I tried to give the privilege to a group of user to do that but could not find the relevant privilege. I can only give them access to the administration page for this repository, but the button is disabled.

Could someone tell me if it's normal and/or how I could improve this workflow?

Comment: The same issue appears with Nexus release 3.34.0. Anyone else that can confirm if it seems for Nexus 3.40.0 too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug. We are working on a fix for it right now, please follow this issue for updates : https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-19384

Comment: Thank you, I will follow the issue